# Sequelize v4 force use writer db instance for findAll read query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize v4 with read write replication

```
replication: {
    read: [
        { host: config.read_db.ip }
    ],
    write: { host: config.db.ip}
},
```

It works well.
But in some cases because of the delay in read db to get updated in real time, I want to use writer replica for some read queries,

Example: If I use orm.User.findAll();

orm.User.findAll uses the reader instance by default but I want it to for to use writer instance.

Is this possible?
I am not able to find the solution to this in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `useMaster` option to the queries which you want them to read exclusively from the `write` replica:

```
   const users = await orm.User.findAll({
      where: {...},
      ...
      useMaster: true
    });
```